# How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-wifi

I know how to get a `<List>` of Android Wifi Scans but I can not figure out the best way to make a list adapter out of them. I would like to just bind SSID and BSSID from a `<List>` of scans to text1 and text2.

Samples of what I have been doing

```
wifi.startScan();
        // get list of the results in object format ( like an array )
        List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();`

        // loop that goes through list
        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            Toast.makeText(this, result.SSID + " " + result.level,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And:

```
private void fillDataFromDb() {
        Cursor scanCursor = Db.fetchAllScans();
        startManagingCursor(scanCursor);`

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list
        // (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[] { WifiDbAdapter.KEY_BSSID,
                WifiDbAdapter.KEY_SSID };

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this
        // case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter scansdb = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.scan_row, scanCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(scansdb);
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to see some code you have too. Are you getting the results like this?: List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

Comment: I'm already doing this to just get toast messages:

`wifi.startScan();
  // get list of the results in object format ( like an array )
  List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

  // loop that goes through list
  for (ScanResult result : results) {
   Toast.makeText(this, result.SSID + " " + result.level,
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @eternalmatt Yes that is exactly how I am getting results and it works great, just don't know how to bind that to a listview

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) 
            {   
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }         
    }    
}
```

**WiFiDemo.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStatus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Status" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Scan" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For ListView- **row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add these permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: What about unregistering the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: textStatus is useless.

Comment: Thank you for this code. How could I scan the Wifi continuously inside the list and return the RSS value?

Answer (score 22):

In addition for the accepted answer you'll need the following permissions into your **AndroidManifest** to get it working:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap an `ArrayAdapter` around your `List<ScanResult>`. Override `getView()` to populate your rows with the `ScanResult` data. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that covers how to create custom `ArrayAdapters` like this.

Comment: can you give me demo of this question

Answer (score 4):

Find a complete working example below:

The code by @Android is very good but has few issues, namely:

1. Populating to ListView code needs to be moved to onReceive of BroadCastReceiver where only the result will be available. In the case result is obtained at 2nd attempt.
2. BroadCastReceiver needs to be unregistered after the results are obtained.
3. `size = size -1` seems unnecessary.

Find below the modified code of @Android as a working example:

WifiScanner.java which is the Main Activity

```
package com.arjunandroid.wifiscanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WifiScanner extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


    WifiManager wifi;
    ListView lv;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Widhwan Setup Wizard");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_scanner);

        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.wifilist);


        wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        this.adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        scanWifiNetworks();
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        scanWifiNetworks();
    }

    private void scanWifiNetworks(){

        arraylist.clear();
        registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

        wifi.startScan();

        Log.d("WifScanner", "scanWifiNetworks");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver= new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.d("WifScanner", "onReceive");
            results = wifi.getScanResults();
            size = results.size();
            unregisterReceiver(this);

            try
            {
                while (size >= 0)
                {
                    size--;
                    arraylist.add(results.get(size).SSID);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.w("WifScanner", "Exception: "+e);

            }


        }
    };

}
```

activity_wifi_scanner.xml which is the layout file for the Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wifilist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Scan Again" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also as mentioned above, do not forget to add Wifi permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

refer below link for getting ScanResult with redundant ssid removed from the list

[duplicate SSID in scanning wifi result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119985/duplicate-ssid-in-scanning-wifi-result/27046433#27046433)