# get the geo-cordinates of the particular building inside a campus

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

I have to create an app which show the map of a campus ,and inside the campus there are 10-12 buildings in the very short distance.I have to show the user's current position inside the campus and directions form one building to another.
As per my knowledge i can't get the geo-cordinates of the particular building because the geo- coordinates are same for the whole campus.

Is there any way to get the location of the user inside a campus?
Or any reference links which may help me.

Thanks

Comment: Geo-Coordinates are not the same for whole campus. Just zoom to the proper level in the google maps and right click on the building you want to know by saying "What is here" then you will see the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think following link contained documents will help you to find out exact location using geolocation.getCurrentLocation().[Documentation]

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to get real GPS coordinates and calculate what exact building is it.
   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android) is appropriate links.
2. If can to walk throw all campuses you can try to check exact building by list of wifi networks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list) is some code.