# How to avoid an automatic toast when we connect to a Wi-Fi network on Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi

In Android, an automatic toast is shown when we connect to a Wi-Fi. Even if we connect programmatically. Is it possible to avoid this auto toast programmatically? If no, explain why. If yes, how can I do that?

It is not useful answers like "don't do that" or "why you want do that". In my case it is important, otherwise I wouldn't asking.

Comment: Probably no because you are not managing the Wi-Fi connection yourself but just asking the system to do the connection for you. It does all the low-level work of starting the Wi-Fi radio and other tasks. And when it finishes the task, the way it is coded is to tell the user about successful connection. I don't think you can control that. Also, I don't see why a Toast that doesn't last longer than couple of seconds could be a problem.

Comment: +1 interesting problem, @FelipeMicaroniLalli do you must use system wifi manager or you can create own program?

Comment: Hi @Lumma! I am using WifiManager. There is another way to access wifi stuffs? Thanks to be nice.

Comment: maybe you will be able connect to wifi manually http://stackoverflow.com/a/7527380/619673

Comment: @Lumma, I did not understand this code very well. What exactly it does?

Comment: this code gives you list of wifi networks

Comment: @Lumma, but how can I connect without the default system toast? That toast where the network name is blue? Do you know?