# Auotoscan in wifi analyzer in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

How to perform an AUTOSCAN in Wi-Fi analyzer application which is continually scan avaliable SSID after specific period? So how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try [wi-fiscanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

now all you have to do is call the onclick function ( content ) using [alarm manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example?answertab=votes#tab-top)