# How to detect whether device has 5Ghz Wi-Fi or not

Tags: android, android-wifi

I spent much time by seaching for solution but without result. So my question is, is there any way how to detect whether device has 5Ghz Wifi or not? It would be nice if it's possible to achieve that. I already analysed `WifiManager` but didn't find proper method or property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As of Android API Level 21, WifiManager has a method called [`is5GHzBandSupported()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#is5GHzBandSupported()) that returns true if the adapter supports 5 GHz band.

Comment: how to determine if 5GHz available on devices running API level <21?

Comment: I suggest using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261908/2313512) below.  It's not perfect, but it might work in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Our approach is to look for the results of a wifi scan and look for a signal of 5GHz. That's not a good solution, 'cause it would give false negatives, but if your context is a venue where you can assure that there are 5GHz wifis near you, it can solve the issue.

See: [How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

The data you can extract from a wifi scan (look for the frequency value):
[image: the data you can extract from a wifi scan]
<sub>(source: [fewlaps.com](http://fewlaps.com/xtra/androidWifiList.png))</sub>

Hope it helps!

Comment: in my case for 5ghz i am getting 2467 frequency please help.

Comment: Probably it's a A/C router, with two signals...?

Comment: Does it mean this approach will only work if there are 5GHz networks around?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what the answer says :·)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using below code snip

```
        WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        Class cls = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiManager");
        Method method = cls.getMethod("isDualBandSupported");

        Object invoke = method.invoke(wifiManager);
        boolean is5GhzSupported=(boolean)invoke;
```