# How to know device have dual wifi band or single wifi band programmatically?

Tags: android, wifi

In general older device have one single slot band which is **2.4ghz** and newer device contain **5ghz** band slot so there is one method **is5GHzBandSupported()** but newer device only have single slot of **5ghz** so it is not working in that case so please can any one help me to get both slots.

Comment: @Fantõmas i want to check that if device support wifi and hotspot at a time or not? if device have slot 2.4 and 5 then it will be supported of device have only single either of 2.4 or 5 then it will not supported. so i want to check this

Comment: OK. And what did you try?

Comment: now i dont know how to achevie this?

Answer (score 1):

As of Android API Level 21, WifiManager has a method called is5GHzBandSupported() that returns true if the adapter supports 5 GHz band.

Excerpt from here:
[How to detect whether device has 5Ghz Wi-Fi or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607371/how-to-detect-whether-device-has-5ghz-wi-fi-or-not/20261908)

Comment: i want to check that if device support wifi and hotspot at a time or not? if device have slot 2.4 and 5 then it will be supported of device have only single either of 2.4 or 5 then it will not supported. so i want to check this – Yash chandvani