# Connect to a Public wifi Network from Android Code?

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi

I am developing an Android App that requires me to scan all available public wifi networks and connect to the one with **highest signal strength**. Can this be achieved is so HOW?

Right now my app just turns on wifi and connects to a saved network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First have a look at the official help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

then look around and found something like that:

[How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

`ScanResult` gives the rssi (`level`)that can be used to select the appropriate network:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

Here's a simple code to scan:

```
WifiManager wifi= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifi.startScan();
// get list of the results in object format ( like an array )
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();`

// loop that goes through list
for (ScanResult result : results) {
  Toast.makeText(this, result.SSID + " " + result.level,
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Remember you need permsissions in your `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**UPDATE:**

To create a network by SSID I use the following:

```
private boolean addNetworkAndActivate(ScanResult scanResult) {

    WifiConfiguration wc = null;

    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : configs) {
        try {
            if (wifiConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + scanResult.SSID + "\"")) {
                wc = wifiConfiguration;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    // not configured, create new
    if (wc == null) {
        wc = new WifiConfiguration();

        ConfigurationSecuritiesV8 conf = new ConfigurationSecuritiesV8();
        conf.setupSecurity(wc, conf.getScanResultSecurity(scanResult), "7ej8e4jka9");
        wc.SSID = "\"" + scanResult.SSID + "\"";

        int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);

        if (res == -1)
            return false;

        if (!wifiManager.saveConfiguration())
            return false;
    }

    boolean active = wifiManager.enableNetwork(wc.networkId, true);

    return active;
}
```

Classes:

```
public class ConfigurationSecuritiesV8 extends ConfigurationSecurities {

    static final int SECURITY_NONE = 0;
    static final int SECURITY_WEP = 1;
    static final int SECURITY_PSK = 2;
    static final int SECURITY_EAP = 3;

    enum PskType {
        UNKNOWN, WPA, WPA2, WPA_WPA2
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ConfigurationSecuritiesV14";

    private static int getSecurity(WifiConfiguration config) {
        if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)) {
            return SECURITY_PSK;
        }
        if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP) || config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)) {
            return SECURITY_EAP;
        }
        return (config.wepKeys[0] != null) ? SECURITY_WEP : SECURITY_NONE;
    }

    private static int getSecurity(ScanResult result) {
        if (result.capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
            return SECURITY_WEP;
        } else if (result.capabilities.contains("PSK")) {
            return SECURITY_PSK;
        } else if (result.capabilities.contains("EAP")) {
            return SECURITY_EAP;
        }
        return SECURITY_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getWifiConfigurationSecurity(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig) {
        return String.valueOf(getSecurity(wifiConfig));
    }

    @Override
    public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {
        return String.valueOf(getSecurity(scanResult));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupSecurity(WifiConfiguration config, String security, String password) {
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
        config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
        config.allowedProtocols.clear();

        final int sec = security == null ? SECURITY_NONE : Integer.valueOf(security);
        final int passwordLen = password == null ? 0 : password.length();
        switch (sec) {
        case SECURITY_NONE:
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE);
            break;

        case SECURITY_WEP:
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE);
            config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
            config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
            if (passwordLen != 0) {
                // WEP-40, WEP-104, and 256-bit WEP (WEP-232?)
                if ((passwordLen == 10 || passwordLen == 26 || passwordLen == 58) && password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]*")) {
                    config.wepKeys[0] = password;
                } else {
                    config.wepKeys[0] = '"' + password + '"';
                }
            }
            break;

        case SECURITY_PSK:
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            if (passwordLen != 0) {
                if (password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}")) {
                    config.preSharedKey = password;
                } else {
                    config.preSharedKey = '"' + password + '"';
                }
            }
            break;

        case SECURITY_EAP:
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
            // config.eap.setValue((String)
            // mEapMethodSpinner.getSelectedItem());
            //
            // config.phase2.setValue((mPhase2Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
            // == 0) ? "" :
            // "auth=" + mPhase2Spinner.getSelectedItem());
            // config.ca_cert.setValue((mEapCaCertSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
            // == 0) ? "" :
            // KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.CA_CERTIFICATE +
            // (String) mEapCaCertSpinner.getSelectedItem());
            // config.client_cert.setValue((mEapUserCertSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
            // == 0) ?
            // "" : KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.USER_CERTIFICATE +
            // (String) mEapUserCertSpinner.getSelectedItem());
            // config.private_key.setValue((mEapUserCertSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
            // == 0) ?
            // "" : KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.USER_PRIVATE_KEY +
            // (String) mEapUserCertSpinner.getSelectedItem());
            // config.identity.setValue((mEapIdentityView.length() == 0) ? "" :
            // mEapIdentityView.getText().toString());
            // config.anonymous_identity.setValue((mEapAnonymousView.length() ==
            // 0) ? "" :
            // mEapAnonymousView.getText().toString());
            // if (mPasswordView.length() != 0) {
            // config.password.setValue(mPasswordView.getText().toString());
            // }
            break;

        default:
            LogBridge.d(TAG, "Invalid security type: " + sec);
        }

        // config.proxySettings = mProxySettings;
        // config.ipAssignment = mIpAssignment;
        // config.linkProperties = new LinkProperties(mLinkProperties);

    }

    private static PskType getPskType(ScanResult result) {
        boolean wpa = result.capabilities.contains("WPA-PSK");
        boolean wpa2 = result.capabilities.contains("WPA2-PSK");
        if (wpa2 && wpa) {
            return PskType.WPA_WPA2;
        } else if (wpa2) {
            return PskType.WPA2;
        } else if (wpa) {
            return PskType.WPA;
        } else {
            LogBridge.d(TAG, "Received abnormal flag string: " + result.capabilities);
            return PskType.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplaySecirityString(final ScanResult scanResult) {
        final int security = getSecurity(scanResult);
        if (security == SECURITY_PSK) {
            switch (getPskType(scanResult)) {
            case WPA:
                return "WPA";
            case WPA_WPA2:
            case WPA2:
                return "WPA2";
            default:
                return "?";
            }
        } else {
            switch (security) {
            case SECURITY_NONE:
                return "OPEN";
            case SECURITY_WEP:
                return "WEP";
            case SECURITY_EAP:
                return "EAP";
            }
        }

        return "?";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpenNetwork(String security) {
        return String.valueOf(SECURITY_NONE).equals(security);
    }
}
```

And

```
public abstract class ConfigurationSecurities {
    /**
     * @return The security of a given {@link WifiConfiguration}.
     */
    public abstract String getWifiConfigurationSecurity(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig);

    /**
     * @return The security of a given {@link ScanResult}.
     */
    public abstract String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult);

    /**
     * Fill in the security fields of WifiConfiguration config.
     * 
     * @param config
     *            The object to fill.
     * @param security
     *            If is OPEN, password is ignored.
     * @param password
     *            Password of the network if security is not OPEN.
     */
    public abstract void setupSecurity(WifiConfiguration config, String security, final String password);

    public abstract String getDisplaySecirityString(final ScanResult scanResult);

    public abstract boolean isOpenNetwork(final String security);

    public static ConfigurationSecurities newInstance() {
//      if (Version.SDK < 8) {
//          return new ConfigurationSecuritiesOld();
//      } else {
            return new ConfigurationSecuritiesV8();
//      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx Seraphim .. BSSID could be used to distinguish between public networks.. But How could i use the result.level values to choose the one with highest strength???

Comment: Are you asking me how to sort a array of signed integer? ;)

Comment: Collections.sort( publicnetworks, new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(ScanResult lhs, ScanResult rhs) {
                        return (lhs.level <rhs.level ? -1 : (lhs.level==rhs.level ? 0 : 1));
                    }});
                int i = publicnetworks.size();
                List<ScanResult> bestnetwork = new ArrayList<ScanResult>(1);
                bestnetwork.add(publicnetworks.get(i));

Comment: i managed to develop this ... but how to actually acquire the lock on ''bestnetwork'?

Comment: What do you mean with "lock"?

Comment: When you kno the ssid e the bssid you can manage to create a new wifi connection. Whait 2 minute and I will update my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028358/deleting-all-videos-in-android-gallery-loop-not-working ... could you kindly answer this question as well ..

Comment: Yes thanks a lot... i appreciate the effort you put into your answers.. but could you please cut it down to connecting to a public server only ..??i would appreciate that.

Comment: What do you mean with "connect to a public server only". Anyway if I response to your question please accept the answer and (I'll appreciato) upvote it. Open a new question and be more precise on what you're asking for. Thanks.

Comment: http://kmansoft.com/2010/04/08/adding-wifi-networks-to-known-list/ ... got the answer here :)

Comment: @Seraphim's can you please help me with my problem.. I used youre code, but stucked at this error - `Error:(151, 43) error: cannot find symbol variable wifiManager`
I'm working in Android Studio 1.3.2... How I can fix this error? Tried clean build and rebuild project, but it doesnot helped =(

Comment: @vladimir using context (an Activity, ...) you get wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: @Seraphim's but if I'm using Service?

Comment: @vladimir use context = getApplicationContext()