# Adding wifi locations in google map near by the user

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-intent

I want to add my wi-fi locations in google map near by the user  Auto discovery of hotspot using Lat Long coordinates (Update message/news update when a hotspot is nearby).Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? We can't do all the work for you.

Comment: i can track only my location in google map till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the WifiManager Class (and take a look at getscanResults()) [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()).
This will return the list of all the hotspots found.

And [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) is how you can add a marker.

You will need to run a loop from 0 to the size of the list that you get. And in each Iteration, add a marker of your current position .

Comment: This is as far as anyone can go to help you. Dont expect someone else to do your homework for you. I have provided the links , you should be able to get it work

Comment: you wanted some code, I can't guarantee it will work, but you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7527380/2670775

Comment: API means an interface . I dont understand what using 'API' means.

Comment: i have my website which contains the list of all wifi so can it help me out?

Comment: Can i have a look at your website ?

Comment: I cannot continue such a long discussion here. You will have to ask a new question. If you want help from users , you appreciate their effort by click on the tick.

Comment: sir please tell me will it be helpfull or not.?

Comment: That will be fairly hard to process, unless you own the website