# How to connect the android wifi by giving the correct authentication details

Tags: android, wifi

I am new to android i want to connect the WiFi by giving the username and password in program itself.i am using the below code.. it only enable the default network..how can i authenticate and get connected by using the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toggleWiFi(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi Enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void toggleWiFi(boolean status) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (status == true && !wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        } else if (status == false && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to do, but first have a look at the official doc of wifi Manager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

1. Scan the network:

```css
WifiManager wifi= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifi.startScan();
// get list of the results in object format ( like an array )
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();`

// loop that goes through list
for (ScanResult result : results) {
  Toast.makeText(this, result.SSID + " " + result.level,
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Thier are are some links that helped to understand the scan well, [How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

Note: There are three types of WIFI networks, ScanResult gives the rssi (level)that can be used to select the appropriate network:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

2. You need permsissions in your manifest.xml:

```css
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

3. ```css
   //First, instantiate a WifiConfiguration object and fill in the network’s SSID

   WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

   wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
   wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
   wfc.priority = 40;

   //For Open Networks: we need to fill members of WifiConfiguration to specify the network’s security mode.

   wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
   wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

   //For WEP

   wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
   wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
   wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

   if (isHexString(password)) wfc.wepKeys[0] = password;
   else wfc.wepKeys[0] = "\"".concat(password).concat("\"");
   wfc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

   //For WPA, we can set the same values for either

   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
   wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
   wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
   wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
   wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

   wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(password).concat("\"");

   //At last, 

   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
   wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

   if (networkId != -1) {
    // add some logs for failure
   } 
   else
   {
     List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
   for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
       if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();               

            break;
       }           
    }
   }
   ```