# How to discover sony camers through WiFi even camera wifi password is not stored

Tags: android, camera, android-wifi, sony, sony-camera-api

How to search Sony Camera wifi programmatically.

I want to apply same camera connection feature as sony play memories app do.
I want to detect Camera even its wifi password is not stored or currently device wifi is not connected to the camera.

Currently, I am using the Sony Camera Remote API demo which shows device in search list only when our device is already connected with a camera .

Please, some one guide me to achieve same functionality like Sony's remote camera app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Android WifiManager class to get a list of all of the WiFi SSIDs.  Then it's just a matter of filtering out the camera SSIDs which you should be able to do just by filtering on the SSID name string.

See this post for details on how to get a list of Wifi SSIDs:

[How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

Comment: Thank you for your response.i am going to just try this and respond you soon. once its done i will accept your answer