# How to start Andorid Wifi Scan for certain duration?

Tags: java, android

I am using startScan() and getScanResults() for the getting the list of available networks.
But I want to start the scan which shall be done upto 2 mins, so that the Wifi devices list shall be updated as and when found.
How do I achieve this behaviour?

I have followed the link 
[How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)
for the getting the scan results.

Comment: actually you want to stop the scanning after two mins. is it you want?????

Comment: No. I want to start the scan which shall be done upto 2 mins.
Suppose, If I start a scan at 0th second and during 100th second if a new wifi Device is found, the same needs to be updated the Available Wifi Devices List.

Comment: We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).